# What's the best practice of inserting a collection of data into a SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, c#, entity-framework

I am using C#, Entity Framework. SQL Server for the development. I have a method which has two parameters (`int ID, List<String> _listobj`). For each ID, there is a list of obj. All of these IDs and lists will be inserted into different tables in database. So the question is: what's the best practice for this? I have couple of options:

1. In C#, split the `list<obj>` as single value, then create a stored procedure which takes two parameters (`ID, str`), then the C# will call the stored procedure many times depending on the size of the list
2. Pass the `ID` and `list<obj>` as two parameters to the stored procedure and let the stored procedure split the `list<obj>`. This way C# will only call the stored procedure once

Is the second strategy doable? If yes, which is better in terms of performance?

Answer (score 3):

You don't want either of those two options, though #2 is quite close. Option #1 is slow due to being row-by-row *and* each call being its own separate transaction. Even if you wrap all of the Stored Procedure calls into a single explicit Transaction, it will still be slower than a set-based approach.

Option #2 is flawed mainly for the additional work being done in both layers: joining the collection into a single string in the app layer, and splitting the string back out into elements in the data layer. However, the general structure of this idea — passing in just two params: ID and the collection of strings — is the way to go. You just need to use a Table-Valued Parameter (TVP) so that you can iterate through the collection as is, and receive it as a pre-populated Table Variable in SQL Server.

You do this by creating a User-Defined Table Type (which here could be a single `NVARCHAR` column) and using that as the parameter for the collection (hence the "Table"-Valued "Parameter").

The other piece to this puzzle is, on the app code side, creating a method that accepts `int ID, List<String> _listobj` and returns `IEnumerable<SqlDataRecord>`, and then use that method as the "Value" for the `SqlParameter` that is mapped to the TVP. Meaning, something like:

```
private static IEnumerable<SqlDataRecord> SendRows(List<String> RowData)
{
   SqlMetaData[] _TvpSchema = new SqlMetaData[] {
      new SqlMetaData("SomeSomething", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 4000)
   };
   SqlDataRecord _DataRecord = new SqlDataRecord(_TvpSchema);

   foreach (string _CurrentRow in RowData)
   {
      _DataRecord.SetString(0, _CurrentRow);

      yield return _DataRecord;
   }
}
```

Then, you would just pass in `SendRows(_listobj)` as the value for the TVP parameter. When you execute the `SqlCommand`, it will call that method and stream that collection into SQL Server.

The technique shown above requires no additional memory or processing, it just sends the collection as a collection. No need for `DataTable`s or `String.Join`ing or splitting :-).

To see a complete example code setup for this, please see my answer to the following Stack Overflow question: [Pass Dictionary to Stored Procedure T-SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19957132/pass-dictionarystring-int-to-stored-procedure-t-sql/25815939#25815939).

Answer (score 0):

2nd way is doable. You can either pass a comma separated string to the SP and within the SP use a custom sql table value function like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_Split](@text VARCHAR(MAX), @delimiter VARCHAR(5) = ',')

RETURNS @Strings TABLE
(    
    position int IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    value VARCHAR(8000)  
)

AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @index int 
    SET @index = -1 

    WHILE (LEN(@text) > 0) 
        BEGIN  
            SET @index = CHARINDEX(@delimiter , @text)  

            IF (@index = 0) AND (LEN(@text) > 0)  
                BEGIN   
                    INSERT INTO @Strings VALUES (@text)
                    BREAK  
                END  

            IF (@index > 1)
                BEGIN
                    INSERT INTO @Strings VALUES (LEFT(@text, @index - 1))
                END

            SET @text = RIGHT(@text, (LEN(@text) - (@index+LEN(@delimiter)-1))) 
        END
    RETURN
END
```

Or you can define a custom table type like foll and call your SP from C# passing a table variable as 2nd param using SqlDbType.Structured

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[MyCustomType] AS TABLE(
Id int not null
)
```

Comment: You should mention that string manipulation (splits, joins, searches) is slow.  Depending on how often this must be done, I would go with the custom type option you mentioned as my first choice.  Let the application do the splitting.