# sql server stored procedure - collection of data for fields as input

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure to add a collection of values to a field in table.
How I implement it now:
from my .net app, I create a string of comma separated values from an array( eg: resource1, recource2, resoource3...). This string is then send to stored procedure, where it is split and each value is inserted into a table.
my code below

```
ALTER PROCEDURE  [dbo].[resourcetrackerupdate]
@resources varchar(max)

as begin

SET NOCOUNT ON;


DECLARE @MyCursor CURSOR;
DECLARE @ReourceName varchar(max);
BEGIN
    SET @MyCursor = CURSOR FOR
    select [name]  from dbo.splitstring(@resources)

    OPEN @MyCursor 
    FETCH NEXT FROM @MyCursor 
    INTO @ResourceName

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN


            BEGIN TRY
                INSERT INTO resourcetracker ([ResourceName]) VALUES (@ResourceName)
             END TRY
            BEGIN CATCH
    
             END CATCH 
      FETCH NEXT FROM @MyCursor 
      INTO @ResourceName
    END; 

    CLOSE @MyCursor ;
    DEALLOCATE @MyCursor;
END;
```

Now, my requirement is that I need to send multiple field data (as opposed to just one - resourcename - now). So , I will need to send resourcename, resourcesize, assignedto etc to stored procedure to insert into the table as new records.
FYI, these arrays are size of few thousands records.

The long comma separated string approach might not work anymore. How can I change my stored procedure to process all that data?

Comment: You may want to look at [table valued parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/use-table-valued-parameters-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15) as an alternative.

Comment: Why use a cursor here at all? Just insert the rows returned by your proprietary (eek!) split function - it is returning a table! And where is your error handling? Erland discusses different options [here](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql.html) for handling "arrays". Bookmark his main page - lots of useful information.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the best practice of inserting a collection of data into a SQL Server database](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/152347/whats-the-best-practice-of-inserting-a-collection-of-data-into-a-sql-server-dat) See also [How to pass table value parameters to stored procedure from .net code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5595353/how-to-pass-table-value-parameters-to-stored-procedure-from-net-code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the drive is the source, because that could define the best way.
Now, i will assume there is some internal logic to the procedure.
Possibilities:

- send it as json/xml and parse it using MSSQL functions
- send it as a table valuable
- place it into a temporar table and process it in procedure

Comment: I went with sending XML data. I would have preferred json, but the sql server version is 2012, hence no support for json.